# panel data: give value of the last year to all the observations of the other years

Tags: panel, stata

- I have x farmers.
- Each farmers has a variable region indicating where he lives.
- For each farmer I have data of multiple years. (however, unbalanced
  panel!)

If for one farmer, variable Z == 0, then I want to change the variable region for all observations of that farmer into the value of the last year of region for that farmer.

For instance:

```
farmID   - year     - region    - Z
1        - 2004     - BE100     - 0
1        - 2005     - BE100     - 0
1        - 2006     - BE112     - 0
```

Should become

```
farmID   - year     - region    - Z
1        - 2004     - BE112     - 0
1        - 2005     - BE112     - 0
1        - 2006     - BE112     - 0
```

I tried:

```
by farmID, if Z==0: replace region[n] = region[_N]
```

But that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1363661-panel-data-give-value-of-the-last-year-to-all-the-observations-of-the-other-years Telling people about cross-posting is polite in any forum, and not doing is widely deprecated.

Comment: Hi Nick, in all the cases that I cross-posted, I always give the answer under both posts with a link to the place where the answer was first given. But I understand your concern given that not everybody does that. I was not aware of the fact that people prefer to know it in advance.

Comment: Knowing it in advance is crucial. Even if people monitor all possible sites, they can't monitor them all simultaneously. The first time I see a question, I want to know if it has been posted elsewhere, so I don't waste my time answering it (unless I can improve on existing answers). Even if people only look at one site and also never answer questions, telling everyone in advance costs nothing much (you need to give one URL, seconds' work) and is a basic courtesy.

Comment: Note further, although I don't stress this point myself, that some people think that **any** simultaneous cross-posting is disrespectful of each forum.

Comment: Point taken Nick. It won't happen again but know that I did not want to do any harm. I like both forums equally btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bysort farmID (year) : gen last_region = region[_N]
#assuming Z does not vary within farmers
replace region = last_region if Z == 0
```

Comment: It's important for a fail-safe solution to sort on year within each panel.